# How to install Vim text editor in Android?

Tags: text-editor

How do I install [Vim text editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_(text_editor)) in Android?

Comment: See https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Text_Editors

Answer (score 2):

[DroidVim](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.droidvim&hl=en) is a Vim clone text editor ported for Android. Vim 8 (huge version, multi language), grep, diff and ctags are ready to use.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Type "pkg install vim" in any Android emulator like termux.

Comment: `pkg` command is a shell script - a wrapper around `apt`. And it's specifically a part of only Termux, not other terminal emulators. Termux provides a minimal Linux environment and `.deb` package repositories, others don't.